# How to programmatically turn on Bluetooth on iOS 10

Tags: bluetooth, ios10

How to enable bluetooth, when:

```
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    NSString * state = nil;
    switch (central.state) {
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
        // Power Off
        // how turn on?
        break;
    }
}
```

Interested iOS 10.

Comment: You can't. It's up to the user to turn it on or off.

Comment: @Larme But Watch application on the IPhone there is a possibility to turn on bluetooth from the program.

Comment: Watch.app is an Apple application. That's why it is allowed to do so. I haven't seen any change in documentation that allow user to switch on/off bluetooth. The best it can do, it show the system pop-up to go to settings by calling CoreBluetooth methods. All other way should be for jailbroken devices or using private API that should get you rejected from AppStore Reviews.